# Value after evaluation of the code

Tags: java

`int x[] = {4,3,7,8,9,10}` is an array. What will be the value of `q` after evaluating `q = x[2] + x[5] * x[1]`?

I tried to solve it and my answer came 51 but when I checked my answer on internet it was 37. Also tell how it is evaluated.

Comment: Because it evaluates the multiplication operation first and then addition (x[2] + (x[5] * x[1]))=37

Answer (score 2):

Java array is indexing as '0' base array

```
so x[2] = 7
   x[5] = 10
   x[1] = 3
```

then evaluate as BODMAS

7 + 10*3 = 37